# Why DCT-III is not used as forward transform for image compression applications?

Tags: transform, dct, image-compression, image-processing

DCT-II is the most widely used type for image compression. This is due to its "Energy Compaction" property. According to this property, a good enough reconstruction of a natural image can be obtained using the initial coefficients of the transformed image.

I wrote a simple script in MATLAB where I took cameraman image (256x256 - greyscale), took its DCT-III [Using dct(x,"Type",3) function first row-wise then columns wise].

```
I=im2gray(im2double(imread("cameraman.jpg")));
I_dct_3 = zeros(256,256);
for j=1:256
    I_dct_3(:,j) = dct(I(:,j),'Type',3);
end
for i=1:256
    I_dct_3(i,:) = dct(I_dct_3(i,:),'Type',3);
end
```

Then I multiplied it with a mask of same size but with bottom right, rightmost and bottom-most cells as '0'. Mask was:

```
mask = ones(256,256);
for i=128:256
    mask(i,:) = mask(i,:).*0;
end

for j=128:256
    mask(:,j) = mask(:,j).*0;
end
```

I used element-by-element multiplication to get masked coefficients:

```
 I_dct_3 = I_dct_3.*mask;
```

Then, I took inverse DCT-III:

```
for j=1:256
    I_rec_dct_3(:,j) = idct(I_dct_3(:,j),'Type',3);
end
for i=1:256
    I_rec_dct_3(i,:) = idct(I_rec_dct_3(i,:),'Type',3);
end
figure,imshow(I_rec_dct_3);
```

The results were the same as what we would get using DCT-II.

[image: Reconstructed Image]
[image: Original Image]

So I wanted to ask:

**Q) It means both DCT-II and DCT-III show the same "Energy Compaction" property?**

**Q) Why DCT-III is not recommended as a forward transform?**